# How do you do pattern rules with arithmetic in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

My Makefile contains the following rules:

```
result-n1 : inputs
        foo $^

result-n2 : result-n1
        hashandmash $^ > $@

result-n3 : result-n2
        hashandmash $^ > $@

# ... [~ 50 more lines omitted for clarity]

result-n20 : result-n19
        hashandmash $^ > $@
```

I would love having just one pattern rule. This would be much clearer and would avoid the hard-coded limit at `20`.

But how would you do this? How do you say that `result-n`*x* depends on `result-n`*x-1*? I only see inelegant solutions (like naming my files in base 1, e.g., `result-nIIIIIIII`).

PS&FWIW, I use `GNU Make 3.81`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, directly.  You can create a pattern rule for `result-%` that has no prerequisites, then you can declare the prerequisites separately:

```
result-n1: inputs
        foo $^

result-%:
        hashandmash $^ > $@

result-n2: result-n1
result-n3: result-n2
  ...
result-n20: result-n19
```

Comment: Thanks! That is already clearer and simpler than my example Makefile.